# DMS replication Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, data-migration, aws-dms

I have set up a DMS replication with

Source - SQL Server onPrem
Target - Aws MySQL
Class- dms.c5.4xlarge
Engine version-3.4.4

it was both full and incremental data . After couple of hours the job started failing and the logs started filling up in my source system.

Last Error Fatal error has occurred Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:] [] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component ; Stream component ' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c: Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Has any one encountered similar issue?

Comment: I am also getting same issue so please share if you got any update related to this issue